# Trigger button click event while executing thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous

I am executing a thread that runs a C# method. During the execution of the method I have set some checkpoints to update the UI of the MainWindow.

The update is about triggering a button click placed in the MainWindow.

The button click c# code

```cs
private void ProjectLogsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //table's name
    TextBlock1.Text = GetTableName(SQLServerConnectionDetails(), "LOG");         

    //calling an sql query to fetch data to datagrid
    PullDataFiles(SQLServerConnectionDetails(), HomePageTab.Header.ToString().Split(" - ")[1], GetTableName(SQLServerConnectionDetails(), "LOG"), datagrid, 1);
    }
}
```

To tackle so far this trivial problem, for which I don't have a clue why is not working, I have approached two different ways:

1. Approach 1 - Using IProgress

```cs
public class UpdateUI
{
    public Button ButtonLogs { get; set; }
}

public void RunCalculationsMethod(string connectionstring, string foldername, string delimeter, Button button_click, IProgress<UpdateUI> progress_ui)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            
            var calculations_query_proc1 = RunProcedureCalculations("EXEC [dbo].[proc1]", foldername, delimeter, 0);

             using SqlCommand sqlCommand_proc1 = new SqlCommand(calculations_query_proc1, sqlConnection);
             {
                 Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Executing: {0}", calculations_query_proc1));

                 sqlCommand_proc1.CommandTimeout = 60 * 5;

                 sqlCommand_proc1.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
            
             progress_ui.Report(new UpdateUI {ButtonLogs = button_click});

            Thread.Sleep(10000); //I just freeze the thread to check if the button is triggered
        }
    }
}

public void UpdateProgressUI(Button ButtonViewLogs)
{
    ButtonViewLogs = ProjectLogsButton;
    ButtonViewLogs.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.ProjectLogsButton_Click);
}

private async void RunCalculationsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IProgress<UpdateUI> pg_ui = new Progress<UpdateUI>(pg_ui => UpdateProgressUI(pg_ui.ButtonLogs));

    //Update the UI
    string getconnectionstring = SQLServerConnectionDetails();
    TextBlock sqltextcalculation = SQLSuccessfulTextCalculations;
    Button projectlogs = ProjectLogsButton;
    await Task.Run(() => RunCalculationsMethod(getconnectionstring, String.Format("C:\\folder_path\\"), ";", projectlogs, pg_ui));
}
```

2. Approach 2 - Using Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke

```cs
public void RunCalculationsMethod(string connectionstring, string foldername, string delimeter, Button button_click, IProgress<UpdateUI> progress_ui)
{
    //Code as posted above
    
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => button_click.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.ProjectLogsButton_Click)));
    
    //The rest of the code
}
```

None of the two approaches can successfully trigger the button click *ProjectLogsButton_Click*. I literally have no clue why none of the two approaches may apply. One of my concerns is that *ProjectLogsButton_Click* calls methods like **SQLServerConnectionDetails()** that it is out of the thread. But if this was the case, I guess that VS 2019 would have rained an error.

Comment: Do you want the button to be clicked by the program?

Comment: @BForce Yeah I want while the thread is executing to be triggered automatically. To trigger the button_click and the content of the button.

Comment: _"It is a question due to my poor knowledge of the topic"_ -- that's not a reason to close a question. Opinion-based is, but I don't see that this question is particularly opinion-based. It _does_ seem incompletely stated, but based on your acceptance of the answer below, it seems that you were able to get the information you needed in spite of that. So while I don't find the question useful, others might.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I agree with but we judge a question as useful or non-useful based on our knowledge and experience. And profoundly I don't have that level of experience. That is why I proposed to close it. Indeed the answer provided helped me solve my problem.

Comment: _"we judge a question as useful or non-useful based on our knowledge and experience"_ -- I should hope not. The stated charter of Stack Overflow is to create a corpus (database) of useful programming questions with useful answers. Every question will be, by definition, outside the knowledge and experience of the person who asks it. Some questions may be not-useful for other reasons (such as irreproducibility, lack of clarity, opinion-based, etc.) but these judgments should be made as objectively as possible, and one's own experience and knowledge should play as little part in that as possible.

Comment: In any case...if you want an action taken on your question that you're not able to do yourself, the best approach is to use a custom flag for a moderator. They are best-equipped both to take action, as well as to judge whether that action fits within the goals and policies of the site. It's not appropriate to ask other users on the site for them to apply certain moderation actions.

Comment: Ok @PeterDuniho thanks for the time you dedicated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line below:

```
ButtonViewLogs.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.ProjectLogsButton_Click)
```

...attaches an event handler to the `Click` event of the `ButtonViewLogs` button. It doesn't trigger the event. To trigger the event you need code like this:

```
ButtonViewLogs.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
```

This will trigger the event, but nothing will happen if there is no handler attached. So you need to have both. You need to have a handler attached, and then you need to trigger the event.

Attaching the handler needs to be done only once, and it is usually done during the initialization stage of the `Window`. If you attach it more than once, the handler will also be invoked multiple times per event, and you rarely want that. If you are using a visual designer, attaching the handler is normally done automagically by the designer. Your responsibility is just to write the code inside the handler.

Triggering the event can happen any number of times. You can trigger the event using the [`Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) class like this:

```
var progress = new Progress<Button>(
    button => button.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent)));

//...

progress.Report(ButtonViewLogs);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Theodor. It worked for me as expected. In general do you think that I can open as many <Progress> classes as I want? Or there is any drawback in program execution?

Comment: @NikSp yes, you can have any number of `Progress` objects, they are not heavy at all. They are just an abstract and convenient way to delegate work to the `Dispatcher`.

Comment: So just re-checking if I was clear in the first place, opening three occurrences of Progress<Button> like ```progress_1 = new Progress<Button>(
    button => button.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent)));```, ```progress_2 = new Progress<Button>(
    button => button.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent)));```, and ```progress_3 = new Progress<Button>(
    button => button.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent)));``` in case I want to click 3 different buttons. This would not add extra latency in my execution right?

Comment: @NikSp nope, all these `Progress` objects will delegate work to the UI thread. As long as the UI thread is not blocked or overwhelmed, the events will be triggered practically instantly.

Comment: Ok, I see. That was my initial conclusion when I asked about the Progress objects. So is there any way to modify the progress<Button> to include in a "chameleon" progress thread that does also other changes rather than only the button click?...Something like ```progress<AllChanges>(progress_all => (TextBoxText, button.RaiseEvent....));``` I think it would be more sufficient right?

Comment: @NikSp I wouldn't expect it to be more efficient. If the total amount of work is the same, however you split or merge it should not make much of a difference. I would be more concerned about making the code more readable and maintainable. In case you find that you have performance issues, it would be quite unlikely that the `Progress` objects will be the culprits. I would look at optimizing the code inside the `Click` event handlers instead.

Comment: @NikSp this should be a separate question I think. 